# Gradient button android with alpha effect

Tags: android, gradient, android-button, android-selector

I am trying to create a button in android with gradient + alpha effect but not getting it exactly what I wish to do.

Here is the image of the button which i would like to get :-

[image]

I am using the below selector for my button style & effects :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="180" android:centerColor="#657377" android:endColor="#AFFFFFFF" android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:type="linear"/>

            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

If anyone has any idea please kindly help me. Thanks

Comment: It seems you need a **radial**, rather than a **linear** gradient.